# Is maxima of a function always greater than the minima??

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

Is maxima of a function always greater than the minima

Like in the case of $x$$+$$\frac{1}{x}$
the maxima is $-2$ and the minima is $2$.
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n06T6.jpg)

Comment: If you're talking about absolute maxima/minima, then the answer is yes. The absolute maximum will always be greater than the absolute minimum. If you're talking about local extrema, you've just provided an excellent counterexample to your claim (:

Comment: What if the function is constant?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Then the maxima are greater than the minima, but not strictly so (as they are, in fact, equal).

Comment: You seem to labour under the delusion that "maxima" is a standalone word that indicates a value such that there is an open subset of the domain such that the value is the maximum of the restriction of the function to said subset. This is not the case: "maxima" is the English word for the plural of "maximum", whereas a value such as the one I described is called a "local maximum". Hence sentences such as: "Find the local maxima of his function". Same for minimum/minima.

Comment: when first derivative vanishes ...for a second derivative negative, the  extremum is maximum and when positive extremum is a minimum... with the difference of extrema values is positive definite ..